# I would like to get a detailed explanation on how we can upload file to google drive from an hybrid application using javascript

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a hybrid mobile application which requires a file upload to google drive via javascript. It's working fine for me with web application. But come to mobile side it require a redirect url. How can we achieve that?

This is my code.

But using the same code on mobile(Hybrid) applications it need redirect URL. The authorization part is not working. I did not get back the token.

```
<button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var clientId = 'client_id';    
    var apiKey = ' ----';    
    var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'

    function handleClientLoad() {
        // Step 2: Reference the API key
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    }

    function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true }, handleAuthResult);
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        console.log(authResult);
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            makeApiCall();
        } else {
            authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
            authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
    }

    function handleAuthClick(event) {
        // Step 3: get authorization to use private data
        gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false }, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
    }

    // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
    function makeApiCall() {
      ///  gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', RetrieveARSettingsAttachment);
      gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);
    }   
</script> 
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```